# Indexing the Log Files

Tags: search, hadoop, indexing, elasticsearch, bigdata

We have log files from all servers in HDFS with following directory  format yyyy-month/yyyy-month-day/yyyy-month-day-hr-minute-second which are transferred via Apache Flume to HDFS.

example: 
partition_month_utc=2013-12/partition_day_utc=2013-12-01/partition_minute_bucket=2013-12-01-00-00/cdc-hpcblx002-03_logmon_1.1385884809507.txt

File Log Format:

```
DATE TIME  HOSTNAME TRANSACTION_ID **T-START**
EVENT 1 
EVENT 2 
EVENT 3
…….
EVENT N
DATE TIME  HOSTNAME TRANSACTION_ID **T-END**  name=value&name2=value2
```

What I have to do is to perform search by Transaction_ID in across all HDFS files and extract content from Transaction start (T-Start) to Transaction End (T-END).  So For that my approach is to create index on all logs file.  This index will be have key as **Transaction_ID** to **filename and file block offset of start transaction and  to end of block offset end transaction** with Map/Reduce program. Also the access has to be fast.  I am kind of new to Hadoop and Indexing so question I have is following:

1) is there alternative design that would better serve  ? 
2) is there any open source available which provide this with tweak ?
3) Also what is best approach to store the index file ?

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One transcation_id maps to one transaction-start-end record or many ? Should your system support range query ?

Comment: Only One transactional id maps to one transaction-start-end.  For now, I only have to support lookup by transaction id.

Comment: Flume supports EalsticSearchSink. ElasticSearch is a text index and search server that you can leverage for your use case. https://github.com/Aconex/elasticflume

Comment: How about HBase? Use transaction-id as the key, and it's coresponding record as the value.